# Specify deploy keys for git repo hosted within Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, ssh-keys, azure-git-deployment

I'm unable to find any documentation relating to deploy keys on specific repositories within Azure DevOps.

Is this a possibility with the ADO platform?  This is widely supported feature in all other git SCM providers, so I assume ADO has a way of managing this as well?

Answer (score 9):

Currently I don't think there is any concept of a "Deploy only" SSH key in Azure DevOps, and don't even get me started on how trying to clone multiple repositories via SSH leads to using keys without a passphrase and requires uploading the key into Secure Files and pulling it down in a special task that requires a bunch of manual steps locally to configure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops